# Mysql table collation change

Tags: mariadb, collation

I have an old table with several Spanish keywords. Its collation is latin1_swedish_ci.
The column with the keywords has a Primary index.
When I try to change collation to utf8_general_ci it is not possible because if finds duplicates.
With that index it is not possible.
What happens is that, for example, "cañada" is taken as "canada" that already exists but they are different words.
That was using phpMyAdmin.
Another try was to export the table as file.sql and using
 `sed 's/STRING_SOURCE/STRING_REPLACE/'`
but at the end mysql source gave me the same error (did expect that :))
I also try that last one with the entire database.

MySQL version 5.5.64-MariaDB
phpMyAdmin, selected the database/table, tab Structure, column with the keywords selected Change and finally from the drop down Collation I selected ut8_general_ci

How can I make this change keeping all the keywords?

Comment: You most likely want utf8mb4_unicode_as or better yet (utf8mb4_0900_as if your version of MySQL supports it).

Comment: Well I just tested the process you describe and I dont get an issue. What version of MySQL are you using. Can you describe exactly how you changed the collation?

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Lunc Change fo utf8mb4_unicode_ci (not _as) was sucessful, no duplicate error output

Comment: @dstonek - Are you sure about utf8mb4_unicode_ci?

Comment: @RickJames That was the first time. I replaced  the db several times by the original one and made some collating changes (and tests with php scripts) and also got errors in the same task which previously I didn't have.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are focused on Spanish, use a Spanish collation, not a generic one:  `utf8_spanish_ci` and `utf8_spanish2_ci`.  They treat `ñ` as a separate letter between `n` and `o`.  Other collations treat `ñ` and `n` as the same.

Meanwhile, `ç=c`.

However `ll` is treated as two `l` by utf8_spanish_ci, while it is treated as coming after `lz` by utf8_spanish2_ci.  (Something about dictionary versus phonebook -- remember those artifacts from ancient history?)

Ref: http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8_collations.html

Once you upgrade to 8.0, there will be two more choices:  `utf8mb4_es_0900_ai_ci` and `utf8mb4_es_trad_0900_ai_ci`.

Ref: http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8mb4_collations.html